# Waiting for the move_base action server to come up

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm facing this issue, getting "Waiting for the move_base action server to come up". I am running all nodes on same laptop.

gazebo + jackal_sim_robot + jackal_sim_mec + jackal_lnav (this contain amcl and move_base) + simple_navigation_goal node. simple navigation goal node is used from link: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutori...

I am able to navigate robot in rviz but when i run simple_navigation_goal node , it print log "Waiting for the move_base action server to come up". ! Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384749/waiting-for-the-move_base-action-server-to-come-up/) by [troyelex](https://answers.ros.org/users/81580/troyelex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error usually means that `move_base` is not running, or that the simple_navigation_goal is not configured with the correct action server name for the move_base node. Do a `rostopic list` and look for a move_base topic ending in `/goal`. The entire path preceding the `/goal` portion is the name of the action server.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [troyelex](https://answers.ros.org/users/81580/troyelex/) on 2021-08-23**:
Thanks for answering.
after using "jackal/move_base" in client code i am able to send goal to mobe_base server.

**Comment by [RRK](https://answers.ros.org/users/95855/rrk/) on 2022-02-01**:
Hey, mine is /move_base/goal and /move_base_simple/goal, but it is still showing the same error. Can you help?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-02-13**:
`move_base_simple` is not an `ActionServer`, the move_base developers just chose a similar name. An `ActionServer` will create 3 topics: goal, feedback and result. In your case, the ActionServer name is probably "/move_base" (but look for those other topic names to be sure.)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-07-23**:
@Mike Scheutzow I'm having the same issue where I have the the server name correct(move_base), but nothing happens. I'm trying to use the action client and server move the robot around while it's getting map information from SLAM. Please take a look at my question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/404057/movebaseaction-server-does-not-seem-to-be-active/)